# User location annotation misplaced when not default

Tags: iphone, sdk, annotations, location, android-mapview

I am showing the user location in an MKMapView. I don't want the default blue circle but instead the red pin.

Therefore I implemented mapView:viewForAnnotation: and made it always return a red pin as the user's location is the only pin I will show on the map view.

When using the default blue circle the location is quite precise but when changing to the red pin it's off quite a lot. It's as if the red pin is dropped precisely and is then moved up so it does not longer show my current position.

This is my code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"MapView: Annotation.");

    MKPinAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:nil];
    [pin setPinColor:MKPinAnnotationColorRed];
    [pin setAnimatesDrop:YES];
    [pin setCanShowCallout:NO];

    return pin;
}
```

I use mapView:didAddAnnotationViews: to center the map view to my current location.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    for(MKAnnotationView *annotationView in views)
    {
        if(annotationView.annotation == _mapView.userLocation)
        {
            MKCoordinateRegion region;
            MKCoordinateSpan span;

            span.latitudeDelta = 0.20;
            span.longitudeDelta = 0.20;

            CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [[_mapView userLocation] coordinate];

            region.span = span;
            region.center = location;

            [_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
            [_mapView regionThatFits:region];
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why my annotation is no longer placed correct when using the red pin instead of the default annotation view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `[pin setAnimatesDrop:NO]` instead of `YES` solved this.